# Can't instantiate a template with iterator tag dispatch

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to implement a small set of functions for my thread pool implementation but I just can't understand how templates are supposed to work here.

```
namespace async {

    template <typename Container>
    using iterator_type = typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::iterator_category;

    template <typename Container, typename Fn, typename... Args>
    void transform(Container& container, Fn&& function, Args&&... args) {

        static_assert(std::is_class<Container>::value);
        static_assert(std::is_class<typename Container::iterator>::value);

        aux::transform(container, std::forward<Fn>(function), std::forward<Args>(args)..., iterator_type<Container>());
    }

    namespace aux {

        template <typename Container, typename Fn, typename... Args>
        void transform(Container& container, Fn&& function, Args&&... args, std::random_access_iterator_tag iter_type) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This generated an error:

> candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'int'
>   to 'std::random_access_iterator_tag' for 3rd argument

```
std::vector<float> float_vector;

async::transform(float_vector, [](int i) { std::cout << "Text\n"; }, 32);
```

And this:

> candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from
>   'std::_Vector_iterator > >'
>   to 'std::random_access_iterator_tag' for 3rd argument

```
void some_function(std::vector<float>::iterator first, std::vector<float>::iterator last) { ... }

std::vector<float> float_vector;

async::transform(float_vector, some_function, float_vector.begin(), float_vector.end());
```

Why does this not work? What 3rd argument? I really wish I could ask a more specific question here but I'm new to C++ generic programming and just can't understand simply by looking at it how is `std::random_access_iterator_tag` treated as a 3rd argument. It's not even a 3rd template parameter in any of the functions. It's not a 3rd argument of anything else too.

Comment: Your parameter pack `Args&&... args` in `aux::transform` function must be at the end of the template parameter list

Comment: Oh. Yes, that did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your parameter pack `Args&&... args` in `aux::transform` function does not appear at the end of the template parameter list, but it should. So, the function should look like following:

```cpp
template <typename Container, typename Fn, typename... Args>
void transform(Container& container,
               Fn&& function,
               std::random_access_iterator_tag iter_type,
               Args&&... args) {
    return;
}
```